# regexp in hdl path for UVM hdl access functions

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, system-verilog-dpi

I wonder can I use a regexp (regular expression) for string given to any HDL access functions in UVM like uvm_hdl_deposit() or uvm_hdl_check_path()?

And if not is it because there is no such functionality in DPI?

I will appreciate any work around if there is no direct way to use a reg exp in HDL access.

Thank all of you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uvm_hdl_deposit routines provide no support for regular expressions. The VPI/DPI does not have a built-in mechanism to do this. You would have to build a database of all names in a scope, then scan through the database finding names that match.

Many tools have command line interfaces that do support some form of regular expressions for commands like deposit so you can avoid writing C interface code.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I did at prev projects but was wonder if there is more proper approach. Now we know there is no a better way to solve an issues with hdl.

Comment: @AlexandrBolotnikov, just be aware of the performance penalty you might encounter if you make too much of the design objects accessible to access. It prevents optimizations of those signals.